# if Controller name is not provided in @html.actionlink control which controller does it take?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I have 2 questions on controllers.

1. I saw a sample code below and wondering which controller this actionlink will method calls. Delete is actually an action method. What if two controllers have same action method name "Delete"?

   `@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.ID })`
2. If no controller name or action method is mentioned in the submit button element like code below, Which controller and action method will it take?

   `<input type="submit" value="Create" />`

Answer (score 4):

I'll answer the 2nd question first, cause it is a part of the 1st one:

2) When you don't specify the controller, it will use current one (if in partial view it uses the controller who's "acting" at the moment of the request).

1) Controllers can have the same Action names, when you have to link a different controller than current one you need to specify it.

[Edit]

Your 2nd question has changed so i update my answer...

The submit button uses the form's "action" value, you can control it as is:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ActionName", "ControllerName"))
{
     ...
     <input type="submit" value="Create" />
}
```

or directly with html tags

```
<form action="@Url.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName")" method="POST">
```

You can also omit controller or/and action parameters if you want to POST using current ones.

Comment: Regarding 2) question's answer : Do you mean that it takes the current controller and action method which returned  this view containing the input html control ? I am aware of the beginform method and my question is what if no controller/action is provided in code like I mentioned in the question . Also I believe for question1) it it  takes the controller name which returns the current view if no controller name is provided .

Comment: Yes, i mean that if you give no parameters at all it will take current controller and action (the one is generating current output). That is true for all MVC helpers except ActionLink (that has the ActionName obligatory parameter).